# How to use autolayout to make a dial pad in iOS?

Tags: autolayout

The requirements are:

- Buttons that number from 0 to 9
- Buttons should be evenly spaced from each other, and fit any screen size

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See the *screenshots* to get how can it be done.

I've kept *width constraint* and *height constraint* *constants* of *NumberPad View* to **300** and **400** respectively. You can change these *constants* and the number buttons will automatically adjust accordingly. Let me know if you want more clarity.

1. Views:
   [image: Views]
2. Animated Views:
   [image: Animated Views]
3. Constraints:
   [image: Constraints (First Half)]
   [image: Constraints (Second Half)]

Comment: Doesn't setting constants on the height and width of the buttons not allow it to scale properly on different screen sizes?

Comment: I've not set width & height constraints for individual buttons. I set width & height constraints for the container view. I just put all the buttons inside a container view & gave width & height constraint to the container view so as to show you how effortlessly the buttons scale even if you change width & height constants of the container view. You can move all the buttons out of this container view & place them in ViewController's main view itself & give the same constraints among buttons & the main view & it will still work effortlessly. Please implement this & let me know.

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding a gif. I've animated the width and height change to show you how the buttons resize according to the change in the container size.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might not be so great if your buttons have a background color, mine was clear.

---

I laid out the 10 buttons in a 4 x 4 grid, with button 0 taking up the entire row on the bottom.

I started by pinning the 0 button to the left, bottom, and right of the container.

I then pinned the top left corner button, the 1 button, to the top and left of the container.

For the 2 button, I pinned to the left of the one button, and the top of the container.

For the top right corner button, the 3 button, I pinned to the left of the 2 button, the top and right of the container.

I made the 2 and 3 button have equal widths and heights of the 1 button.

I repeated this for the remaining buttons, but made sure to make the heights and widths equal to those of the 1 button.

When I finished at the 9 button, I pinned the 0 button to the vertical space above with a constant of zero.

I updated the frames, and was happy with the result.

I made sure to make sure all the pinning had a zero constant.

---

I searched high and low for a solution on Google and Stackoverflow, and couldn't find anything ideal for me, so I decided to do it on my own, and just contribute an answer for record keeping, while helping anyone else out in the process.

Let me know if you have any questions.